# page break inside avoid is not working on cfhtmltopdf

Tags: css, pdf, coldfusion, cfml

I have tried to generate the PDF file by using cfhtmltopdf tag. I am using the coldfusion 16 server. But page-break-inside: avoid; is not working every time my div of content was spited. How can i avoid the div breaking issue? Please help me if you know anyone have the solution for this issue. Thank you :)

```html
<cfhtmltopdf>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <title></title>
      <style>
         .container{
            margin: 20px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            page-break-inside: avoid !important;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <cfloop from="1" to="10" index="i">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="title"> 
               Test Title 
            </div>
            <div class="subtitle">
               This is test sub title
            </div>
            <div class="shortdescription">
               this is the test shortdescription. this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.this is the test shortdescription.
            </div>
         </div>
      </cfloop>
   </body>
   </html>
</cfhtmltopdf>
```

[image]

Comment: Does coldfusion even support 'page-break-inside, page-break-after, page-break-before,..'? I ran into this a while back. I switched to wkhtmltopdf after that